# Taking the average of one column with a certain value in another column Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I want to find the average of one column based on the value of another. So if i have col1 with columns ['1','2'].

```
data = [['A',10],['B',12],[['A',41],['B',14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame('data',columns=['1','2']
df1.head()
```

so how would i create a new column with the average for '1' A and B

Answer (score 0):

You can do do a `groupby` and `transform` to get the mean of each group

```
df1["avg"] = df1.groupby(['1']).transform('mean')

print(df1)
   1   2   avg
0  A  10  25.5
1  B  12  13.0
2  A  41  25.5
3  B  14  13.0
```

---

Or, if you want a literal column of the mean of `A` and `B` you can do the following

```
df1["A_avg"] = df1[df1["1"]=="A"]["2"].mean()
df1["B_avg"] = df1[df1["1"]=="B"]["2"].mean()

print(df1)
   1   2  A_avg  B_avg
0  A  10   25.5   13.0
1  B  12   25.5   13.0
2  A  41   25.5   13.0
3  B  14   25.5   13.0
```